# Security Risk of outbound web calls

Tags: web-application, man-in-the-middle, web-service, rest

What possible risks/attack vectors could be introduced be allowing my server application to make outbound calls to a 3rd party REST API?  The 3rd party REST API is off premises and owned and operated by the 3rd party.

In order to clarify and limit scope let's just focus on attacks that result in impact on our business (so DoS and things like that would count). Let's also assume that it's properly protected via HTTPS. The users will be other businesses and the on-boarding would be controlled, so there's very little room for bad actors to inject themselves as legitimate system users.

The data from the 3rd party is not essential/used/trusted in our system. In fact our calling out is purely a notification of an event being sent in a fire-and-forget scenario.

Comment: I think this question is currently too unspecific. For example I miss the following information: is this 3rd party API essential for the application (i.e. inability to access it means denial of service), are the results from this API included as trusted in the application and can the party actually be trusted that much, is the API access properly protected by HTTPS... - it is not so much the outbound call which is the risk but the use of third party stuff in general.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for your reply. In order to clarify and limit scope let's just focus on attacks that result in impact on our business so like you mentioned DoS. Lets also assume that it's properly protected via HTTPS. The users will be other businesses and the on-boarding would be controlled so there's very little room for bad actors to inject themselves as legitimate system users.

Comment: Sorry @SteffenUllrich missed an answer to your comment in my reply, the data from the 3rd party is not essential/used/trusted in our system in fact our calling out is purely a notification of an event being sent in a fire and forget scenario.

Comment: The risks would be limited to having to trust https isn't broken, and trusting the intersection of the 3rd party and your underlying code.   For instance, what if the 3rd party, or someone who hacked it was able to find a bug in your code and execute arbitrary code in the application calling the 3rd parties API?  Normally APIs return data to whatever calls it, and this is a potential attack vector

Answer (score 2):

> ... our calling out is purely a notification of an event being sent in a fire and forget scenario

In this case there is not much risk **if properly implemented**. Proper implementation means that any possible problems are known and addressed or that your API access is mostly independent from the rest of the application so that even unforeseen problems will not affect your main application.

Such problems might be that the third party does not respond in time or that it sends an unexpected reply - for example a really large reply which eats lots of memory or an unexpected or deliberately malformed reply which might result in buffer overflows or similar bugs on your site. If there is too much dependency or interaction between your main code and the 3rd party API access this might negatively affect the main application (slow down, denial of service) and might even make it possible to take over the application by a malicious third party.

A robust protection against such problems could for example be implemented with [privilege separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation) where the API access runs as a separate process with different privileges (different user with own resource limits, container, sandbox, VM ...) and there is only a small and well defined communication between your main application and this separated API access.